# How can I print the ndarray compelete information?

Tags: python, pandas, statmodels

I have been trying to match the output but I'm not getting the column names I got from df which I put into the statmodels.

```
import pandas
import statsmodels.api as statmodel
df = pandas.read_csv('fastfood.csv')

df = df[['total_fat', 'sat_fat', 'cholesterol', 'sodium','calories']]
X = df[['total_fat', 'sat_fat', 'cholesterol', 'sodium']].values
Y = df[['calories']].values
X = statmodel.add_constant(X)
model = statmodel.OLS(Y, X).fit()

print(model.mse_total.round(2))
print(model.rsquared.round(2))
print(model.params.round(2))
print(model.pvalues.round(2))
```

Output I got:

```
79770.18
0.9
[71.73  9.1   0.6   0.21  0.16]
[0.   0.   0.64 0.07 0.  ]
```

Output I need:

```
79770.18
0.9 
-{0,}71.73 
total_fat 9.10 
sat_fat . ..0.60 
cholesterol 0.21 
sodium... ...0.16 
dtype: float64 
{0,}0.00 
total_fat 0.00 
sat_fat. ..0.64 
cholesterol...0.07 
sodium .. ..0.00 
dtype: float64
```

Comment: Try `model.params.round(2).dtype.names` what is the output?

Comment: @kinshukdua I got **None** for `model.params.round(2).dtype.names`

Comment: What happens if you delete ".values" from the definitions of X and Y?

Comment: @Simone thanks it worked now. You are the BEST

Comment: @AsadKareem it worked for me, see my answer. I don't know why it doesn't for you, maybe you are using an older version of statsmodels (mine is 0.12.2).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to remove the `.values` in the definitions of X and Y:

```
import pandas
import statsmodels.api as statmodel
df = pandas.DataFrame({'total_fat': np.random.rand(100), 
                       'sat_fat': np.random.rand(100), 
                       'cholesterol': np.random.rand(100), 
                       'sodium': np.random.rand(100),
                       'calories': np.random.rand(100)})

df = df[['total_fat', 'sat_fat', 'cholesterol', 'sodium','calories']]
X = df[['total_fat', 'sat_fat', 'cholesterol', 'sodium']]
Y = df[['calories']]
X = statmodel.add_constant(X)
model = statmodel.OLS(Y, X).fit()

print(model.mse_total.round(2))
print(model.rsquared.round(2))
print(model.params.round(2))
print(model.pvalues.round(2))
```

and it gives me the following output:

```
0.09
0.02
const          0.49
total_fat     -0.07
sat_fat        0.14
cholesterol    0.02
sodium        -0.01
dtype: float64
const          0.00
total_fat      0.54
sat_fat        0.21
cholesterol    0.83
sodium         0.89
dtype: float64
```

Comment: Thank you @Simone. One more thing I wanted to ask that how can I get `{0,} 0.49` instead of `const  0.49`?

Comment: Try `print(model.params.rename(index={'const': '{0,}'}).round(2))`.